# Inserting rows into pagedcollectionview, while preserving the location

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, observablecollection

I have to create a grid which allows sorting and filtering. Currently I am able to achive this by binding PagedCollectionView of the data. I would like allow user to insert or delete row from the grid with context menu. User can select a row and right click on the context menu and insert or delete a row. I can delete the current row, but adding row got me stumped. When I insert a new row and since I do not know any values, I insert a blank row and that end up coming at the end of the grid. 
One solution I am working on is to copy the previous row of the gird and using converter, if the row is dirty display blank.
Just curious, is there a better way of inserting row at current place in a grid while keeping sorting and filtering in place?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is interested, what I ended up doing is insert the row in the grid manually with out paged collection view to keep the sorting and in the code behind insert a dummy row.